# Counld not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to setup my react native expo app to use react-redux and after my setup i keep getting the error `Counld not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>` i searched the internent for solution but non of the solution worked in my case.
I'm using Expo 49 SDK and below is my app _layout.js file

```
import FontAwesome from "@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome";
import {
  DarkTheme,
  DefaultTheme,
  ThemeProvider,
} from "@react-navigation/native";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import { SplashScreen, Stack, Slot } from "expo-router";
import React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useColorScheme } from "react-native";
import { AuthProvider } from "../context/AuthProvider";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../redux/store/store';

export {
  // Catch any errors thrown by the Layout component.
  ErrorBoundary,
} from "expo-router";

export const unstable_settings = {
  // Ensure that reloading on `/modal` keeps a back button present.
  initialRouteName: "(tabs)",
  
};

// Prevent the splash screen from auto-hiding before asset loading is complete.
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function RootLayout() {
  const [loaded, error] = useFonts({
    SpaceMono: require('../assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf'),
    DMBold: require("../assets/fonts/DMSans-Bold.ttf"),
    DMMedium: require("../assets/fonts/DMSans-Medium.ttf"),
    DMRegular: require("../assets/fonts/DMSans-Regular.ttf"),
    ...FontAwesome.font,
  });

  // Expo Router uses Error Boundaries to catch errors in the navigation tree.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) throw error;
  }, [error]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loaded) {
      SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [loaded]);

  if (!loaded) {
    return <Slot />;
  }

  return(
    <Provider store={store}  > 
        <RootLayoutNav />
    </Provider>
  );
}

function RootLayoutNav() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();


  return (
 
    <ThemeProvider value={colorScheme === 'dark' ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Stack>
          <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        </Stack>
      </AuthProvider>
      
    </ThemeProvider>
  
    
  );
}
```

without the  everything works so find but adding the  the error comes up. what is the cause of this problem and how can i solve it. Thanks in advance